# Cannot Get Profile And Role In Second Membership Provider

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I use two membership provider in my application, when user key in the username and password, it should check username in first membership provider, if not in first provider, then only search username in second membership provider. But the problem is, everytime it search on second membership provider, the profile and role provider still is first provider. What I do wrong in my code?
Below is my code :

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    MembershipProvider ProviderName = Membership.Providers["MySqlMembershipProvider2"];


    if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) == true)
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
        Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "~/Start.aspx";
    }
    else
    {
        if (Membership.Providers["MySqlMembershipProvider2"].ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) == true)
        {

            RoleProvider RoleName= Roles.Providers["MySqlRoleProvider2"];
            ProviderName.GetUser(Login1.UserName,true);
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Login1.DestinationPageUrl = "~/CL/CLLogin.aspx";
        }
        else
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" connectionStringName="MySQLMembershipConnection" applicationName="/" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider" autogenerateschema="true"/>
    <add name="MySQLRoleProvider2" connectionStringName="MySQLMembershipConnection2" applicationName="/" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider" autogenerateschema="true"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true"/>
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MySQLMembershipConnection" autogenerateschema="true" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"/>
    <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider2" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MySQLMembershipConnection2" autogenerateschema="true" applicationName="/" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="MySQLMembershipConnection" autogenerateschema="true"/>
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider2" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySqlProfileProvider" applicationName="/" connectionStringName="MySQLMembershipConnection2" autogenerateschema="true"/>
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="FullName" provider="MySQLProfileProvider"/>
    <add name="FName" provider="MySQLProfileProvider"/>
    <add name="ClassName" provider="MySQLProfileProvider2"/>
    <add name="Area" provider="MySQLProfileProvider2"/>
  </properties>
</profile>
<sessionState>
  <providers>
    <add name="MySqlSessionStateStore" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore,MySql.Web"/>
    <add name="MySqlSessionStateStore2" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore,MySql.Web"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your login_authenticate is not correctly implemented, you need to handle to authenticate using both providers. by first checking the default provider (if case) and then authenticate against the second provider (in if else) statement. Here is a code sample. you do not need to hardcode the provider2 in the beginning of the authenticate method.

code sample:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        bool foundUser = false;
        List<string> roles = new List<string>();
        roles.Add("GeneralUser");
        // this will call the default MembershipProvider
        if (Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(LoginBox.UserName, LoginBox.Password))
        {
            foundUser = true;
            // do any additional lookups for this type of user (Default MembershipProvider) here
        } // otherwise, explicitly call secondary provider
        else if (
            Membership.Providers["SecondarySqlMembershipProvider"].ValidateUser(LoginBox.UserName,
                                                                                LoginBox.Password))
        {
            foundUser = true;
            roles.Add("SecondaryUser");
            // do any additional lookups relevant to this type of user
        }
        if (foundUser)
        {
            Session["UserId"] = LoginBox.UserName;
            Session["Groups"] = roles;
        }
        e.Authenticated = foundUser;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw this solution before, but I have many roles in first and second role provider. I do not know how to apply this solution to my situation.

Comment: load the roles as comma separated values. so you have it when you need it.

Comment: I tried the solution above, but still do not work. Anything I can do other than this?